# How to activate car mode with a magnet?

Tags: nexus-7, car-dock

The Google Nexus 7 tablet has lots of reed relays and magnets.

Some toggle the screen, others activate the wireless charging dock. I suppose there is a position for activating car mode (never putting screen to sleep). I'd like to put a magnet (or several if necessary) into my car dock, so I can trigger car mode, whenever I put the tablet in there.

Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find a page, that will describe the various positions of the reed relays inside the device.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is NFC Trigger.. there is an app (nfc trigger) that can activate car mode automatically when the tag is close to the tablet

Comment: Yup, you can get NFC tags pretty cheap on the internet.